# End Session in PHP

Tags: php

i have problem in End session, i have MAIN.PHP where my session starts, inside my MAIN.php i  have`<a href = "logout.php">logout</a>` this is the code for my logout.php

```
<?php
 unset($_SESSION['user']);
 unset($_SESSION['pass']);
 session_destroy();
 echo"<script> window.location.href = '../index.php' ; </script>";
 exit();
 ?>
```

after clicking the link logout, when i press the back button i can still access the pages and still it holds my SESSION variables.

Comment: Does it still work if you refresh after hitting the previous button?

Comment: You may want to consider setting the `Location:` header `Header("Location: _url_")` versus a JavaScript redirect. No need to make the client recall the server immediately. Just redirect them after destroying the session. It should be a ***302*** I believe if you are interested in the HTTP Code.

Comment: yes , it is still working.

Comment: @war10ck even i use the header still when i press back, i can access my php.

Comment: To all **the duplicators** please read the post and the comments, It's **NOT** a regular "back button" problem.

Comment: @user2761456 Yes. My apologies. I wasn't clear on that. That's a further enhancement to your code that should be made. That will not solve your underlying problem though. Have a look at some of the duplicate suggestions above. I'm pretty sure you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild stab and say that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971626/session-variables-do-not-get-destroy-even-using-session-destroy#answer-9971669) will solve your problem.

Per the [PHP Docs For session_destroy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> `session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It **does not** unset any of the **global** variables associated with the session, or unset the **session cookie**. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the **session cookie must be deleted**. setcookie() may be used for that.

To sum up what seems to be your problem, the pesky session cookie (which identifies the session) is not being unset. Therefore, when you hit the back button, and `session_start();` appears at the top of your script, the global session variables are still being referenced. As the other answer suggests, try:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

to clear all of the global session data. Also, as the docs say, unset the session cookie.

Comment: thanks for this, im sorry if i find it hard in searching for related titles.

Comment: @user2761456 All good buddy. We're all still learning. That's the nice thing about Stack Overflow. It has some hidden gems that can really solve some big problems. It's just a little tricky to find them some times. No worries man. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 5):

you might want to add `session_start()` in there too

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
 unset($_SESSION['pass']);
 session_destroy();
 header('Location: index.php');
```

also, i personally prefer to unset the entire session like `unset($_SESSION);`, but everyone has their own ways of doing things

Comment: still i can access when i press back